# How can I give read Access to everybody with gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

in my gitolite.conf i can set

```
repo    COOL_REPOSITORY
        RW+     =   me
        R       =   @all
```

This gives me writing access, and all other REGISTERED users have read access to my repository. Now my question is, can i give read access to everybody, not only to users which i have registered by storing their ssh-keys in my keydir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call gitolite from an http VirtualHost configuration, [like I do in my project](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L112).

```
# GitHttp on @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
Listen @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
<VirtualHost @FQN@:@PORT_HTTP_HGIT@>
  ServerName @FQN@
  ServerAlias @HOSTNAME@
  SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
  SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
  ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
  <Location /hgit>
    ...
```

Gitolite doesn't require users to register ssh keys: it is only an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html).

But still calling gitolite through http ensure that you keep other Gitolite features active, like:

- audit trail (in `.gitolite/logs`: you still know at least which IP address did clone/pull/push your repo)
- control access (in case you need to remove the `@all` rule at any moment)

Using directly git-daemon or a direct http access, without using Gitolite at all, would mean renouncing to *any* control access.

Comment: I find this answer very good and short; it compresses the 'official' step-by-step guide into only very few lines. But I'm having trouble; I get this error: **FATAL: warn\tUse of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in join or string at /var/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell line 78, <DATA> line 1.<<newline>>** - any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: @PacMan-- not sure: it would be best to post a new question, with the exact version of gitolite you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Gitolite uses ssh, and I do not think ssh should be used to give access to unregistered users.

Git implements git-daemon and git-http-backend to allow anonymous access via the git:// or http:// protocols, respectively.