# Is it possible to give public access to a private GIT server?

Tags: git, ssh

I have successfully setup a private GIT server using SSH keys and Gitolite, and i was able to clone, pull, push to that server with no issues, but now in order to give access to some repository on this server to any other computer, i need to add the public key of that computer to ssh authorized_keys of this server. I want to know whether I can give public read and write access to this repository without actually adding the ssh public keys ?

I have tried to run git daemon, but i was not able to run it due to some port problems, but i want to know, if even with git daemon is it possible to give both read and write public access without adding ssh keys ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111952/can-gitolite-work-without-users-ssh-keys-for-authorization

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in allowing others to push to your repository, you can do this by just configuring [HTTP transfers](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html). Those can be done over any port you want really, but ports 80 and 443 (the latter for HTTPS) are the ones that are most likely to be open.

Failing that, your easiest approach is almost certainly to use a service elsewhere to host, with you regularly synchronising your local repository with that remote one. The details of what is best there will depend on all sorts of factors (e.g., how public do you really want it to be?)

Comment: i want others to be able to both push and pull from the server i.e. both read and write access, and also i cannot use another public repository, i have to set up or make my server as one.

Comment: basically i want to provide public access, but only within a group or intranet, i want to know if it is possible without actually adding the public keys of other users of the group ?

Comment: @user You _definitely_ need to carefully read that chapter of the Git book that I linked to. It probably comes down to getting that network port open or suffering through the pain of getting ssh set up right. Or setting up a _private_ repository somewhere like GitHub (costs a bit) and getting everyone an account. That's what we actually do…