# Restrict read access in git repo using gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I am using gitolite for git repository restrict the access.

Any one can tell how to configure restrict the branches and how to restrict read permission for particular Dir/file?

Comment: That may be possible in the web interface, but git itself does not support this. People clone the whole repo and get everything. You'd have to create a "censored" second repository that contains only what should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Gitolite overview](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview)

> read access controlled at the repo level,

You either access (clone) the *full* repo or you don't at all.

A sensitive file should typically *not* be in a repo (or be in a private repo), and generated through a [`smudge` filter content driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457006/6309). That '`smudge`' script can (on `git checkout`) check if you are an authorized user and, if yes, fetch the file (from a trusted private source, not from a git repo) and generate on checkout your restricted file.

*Write* access restriction, on the other hand, has always been possible, [as I mentioned 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205192/6309).
With **[VREFS](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html)**, you can enforce all kinds of policies (like [git commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088305/6309), or [based on roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900083/6309).

And yes, you can [restrict pushes based on file/DIR](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME).

You can even use [LDAP groups to restrict gitolite access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113010/6309)

---

For restricting read access based on dir/file or branches/tags except gitolite...

- first even gitolite does not do that
- this is not how a Git repo works: you would have to impose restrictions on the listener (https or ssh) level, that is at the level where [`git upload-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) (done on the server side during a client `git fetch`) is requesting packs: it is called by ssh, or by the [https smart protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol).
  That would involve packs inspection (with [`git verify-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack)), which would slow down considerably clone/fetch operation and has not been done to my knowledge.

Hence my original suggestion to *not* put any restricted/sensitive file ni a git repo.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Vonc. Any other option for restrict read write access based on dir/file or branches/tags except gitolite?

Comment: @vinay I have edited the answer to address your question (as well as to point out to existing *wirte* restriction)