# Can GitoLite and Git Using LDAP and NOT SSH keys

Tags: git, ldap, gitolite

my firm is looking at using git and gitolite but does not want to use SSH keys and work like to use LDAP..  Can this be done??

I never seen this done.. everyplace I have this setup with always used SSH keys

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it without any issue.

You simply need your [Apache to do the authentication part](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite-doc/blob/master/extras/auth.mkd#otherauth-how-to-use-other-authentication-systems-with-gitolite) (since gitolite is only an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html)), and call `gitolite-shell` instead of `git-http-backend`, with `REMOTE_USER` set by Apache (and [used by `gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L71-L72)).

See a detailed example in "[Git with Ldap on Ubuntu with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309)".

The main part of the `httpd.conf` being:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Location /hgit>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    #AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthName "LDAP authentication for Smart HTTP Git repositories"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider myldap companyldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
    Require valid-user
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
</Location>
```

(`@H@` is just a template value, to be replaced by your path)

Comment: but this looks like everyone will have access to everything.. how does gitolite get used in this setup

Comment: @JMSAZ2013 no, it doesn't look like  everyone will have access to everything. First, you have to authenticate yourself (`Require valid-user`), or you won't have access to any repo. Second `gitolite-shell` is called ("`ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/`"), with your id set in the `REMOTE_USER` variable: if gitolite find that you aren't authorized to access a particular repo, it will send back a 403 error (Access denied).