# Remote Git branch authorization

Tags: git, git-branch, bonobo

I am using Bonobo Git Server for hosting my remote git. Is it possible to lock some branches in a repository so that it is only commit-able by authorize people? Other people can create their own branches on the repository and working on it, but not on the branches that has been locked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, because this kind of fine-grained access control level is usually managed by **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)**, and [installing gitolite on Windows is possible but not straightforward](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx).

It would involve Cygwin, with no good way to be called from the IIS instance managing the Bonobo server (as opposed to call [Gitolite from an Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384315/6309)).