# Usernames and password in GIT

Tags: git

I currently have ssh based authentication in my linux private git server. But I want to create usernames and password authentication for it instead of ssh keys. And the users all have windows systems. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a listener which will access the LDAP used by your Windows user (assuming they already must authenticate themselves on their windows workstation).

This is typically an Apache:

- using an [`AuthLDAPURL`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl)
- calling the [`git http backend` script](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend)

See "[Git with Ldap on Ubuntu with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309)" for a concrete example.

If your Windows users do not authenticate themselves, then you need to setup an [ldap server in which you insert some ldif user files](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/openldap/ini_ldap_db.sh.tpl#L13-L26) (like this [ldif file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/openldap/users-usecases.ldif))
Then, the same apache can contact your own ldap server.

Answer (score 0):

Direct use of gitlab, a type of software such as Gitbucket as a remote server, supports not only SSH but also HTTP