# How to configure Git server with LDAP on ubuntu

Tags: git, ldap

I'm trying to configure Git server with LDAP on Ubuntu , but unable to configure this task can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a "Git server".
You can have *listeners* (like NGiNX or Apache HTTP server) in front of Git, which will handle the authentication, and then call Git.

See for instance my answer in "[Git with Ldap on Ubuntu with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309)".