# how to use project name in git clone?

Tags: git, git-clone

I use gitosis to manage git repositories. normally I clone a project with command pattern like this

```
git clone git@host:MyProject.git
```

The full path of MyProject is `/home/git/repositories/MyProject.git`

Today, I want to create a new account to share my project, so I create a account named `share`, with this account, I use `ssh-keygen` to create a ssh key, and put it in gitosis.

Now it can access the project. But the question is: with this account, I have to access repositories with full path:

```
git clone share@host:/home/git/repositories/MyProject.git
```

Does anyone know how to clone it just with the project name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how gitosis (which is [obsolete since 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)) or [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) is working.
See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)" (which applies also for gitosis)

The url of your repo will *always* be `git@host:MyProject.git`, meaning you always access that service through ssh with the account `git`.

You will simply use a different public/private key (share/share.pub) when using that url: that will allow gitosis/gitolite (installed on host) to authenticate you as share and access the MyProject.git in the pre-configured path.

Define a config file: `~/.ssh/config` with in it:

```
host gitosis-share
     user git
     hostname host.com
     identityfile ~/.ssh/share
```

And use the url: `gitosis-share:MyProject.git`

Comment: A former coworker likes to say that "the cure for gitosis is gitolite" :)  [s/git/hali/ if needed]

Comment: Hi, VonC, the problem is so many people(someone I even don't know them) want to clone this project. I can not use public/private key to manage this. can I have a way to share this project just with username and password?

Comment: @会弹钢琴的狼 that is not the question originally asked. The question was: how to access it with the new account named '`share`'. That would imply to distribute the private ssh key, by the way, which isn't really a best practice. But I have answered the question. For a public read-only access, you would need http(s) access: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16759565/6309

Comment: @VonC, Thank you very much :)